# Updating a Table With More than 22 Columns

Tags: scala, slick

Many of us that have used Slick have come across the issue of having a table with more than 22 columns. Thankfully, the following post in the Slick Google group has saved many of us a lot of trouble. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaquery/qjNW8P7VQJ8/ntqCkz0S4WIJ

The problem that I am facing is updating this table that has more than 22 columns. Has anyone come across and solved this issue?

I understand that Slick 2.0 allows for using HLists to get around the 22 column limit. Sadly, I don't have the option to use Slick 2.0 at this time.

**Update**
The approach that I'm currently taking is dropping the row that needs to be updated and then inserting the new record. This works for my purposes, but I would prefer to perform an update, if possible.